# How to print a PDF on both sides?

Tags: printing, pdf

I want to print a PDF on both sides. But, as you see in the following `Page SetUp` tab, the `Two-sided` is said to be `Not available`. How can this be possible?

[image]

My Printer Settings:

```
Printer Model :  FUJI XEROX DocuPrint P205 b
Device URI    :  dnssd://FUJI%20XEROX%20DocuPrint%20P205%20b%20(85%3Aee%3A7f)%200._ipp._tcp.local/
Make and Model:  Fuji Xerox DocuPrint P205 Foomatic/foo2hbpl2 (recommended)
```

If it is caused by the printer driver `foo2hbpl2`. Is there an alternative for solving this?

Comment: “How can this be possible?” Either your printer doesn't support that feature, or the printer driver doesn't support it.

Comment: Are you sure that, in the "General" tab is selected your physical printer, not "Print to file"?

Comment: @SpasSpasov - I selected the printer with name `FUJI-XEROX-DocuPrint-P205-b` .

Comment: Your answer is in the first comment.

Comment: The printer supports this feature. But it needs its driver to be installed. as far as I see, there is not Linux version of driver for this printer on the company website. Now, the question is if there is any doable hack to get this option, functional on your Ubuntu.

Comment: According to the [P205b manual](http://www.fujixeroxprinters.com.au/downloads/uploaded/DocuPrint%20P205%20b%20User%20Guide%20English_ea48.pdf) this printer only supports manual duplex and only in the windows driver.